# Eloquent Is Painfully Slow after Upgrading dblib Driver to pdo_sqlsrv

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, sqlsrv

I have a Laravel app using a SQL Server database. The app is running in a Ubuntu 22.04 environment.
As per [Laravel's recommendation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#mssql-configuration), I recently upgraded the SQL Server driver to `pdo_sqlsrv`, following [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver16#installing-on-ubuntu-with-php-fpm). Previously, we were using `db_lib` from `php-sybase` with [FreeTDS](https://www.freetds.org).

While most queries are now meeting or surpassing the previous load times, the heavy queries are taking up to 5x as long. One particular query that is eager-loading multiple relationships, went from 2.5 seconds to 13 seconds.

I already tried implementing all of Microsoft's [recommendations for improving the performance of PDO_SQLSRV and SQLSRV](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/wiki/Recommendations-for-improving-the-performance-of-PDO_SQLSRV-and-SQLSRV#4-client-side-cursor-queries). The last suggestion of using server-side cursors I was unable to do, since Laravel seemingly does not provide a way of setting that when using their query builder. I did however try playing around with the connection source code, to no avail.

Is there any way to get `pdo_sqlsrv` to match the previous performance?

I've been searching for a solution for a few days now. It feel like I'm missing something, since it does not seem like many other developers are facing this particular problem.

Comment: You have to debug the query, not Laravel. See if the same query takes the same amount on Laravel and run on any terminal directly on the DB. Then also use `EXPLAIN` so you can check what the query is doing...

Comment: Without details on what a "heavy query" is, and what exact options you've already tried, it's not really possible for anyone to answer this.

Comment: @matiaslauriti There are a total of about 15 queries being produced from the query builder pulling the Eloquent model along with eager loading some relationships. The queries being produced by each of the SQL drivers are identical. Therefore, I do not see why the query would be the culprit.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm not sure where you're want elaboration. The heavy query I'm referring to is one that eager loads multiple relationships. I tried all the options as detailed in the provided link, namely, disabling MARS, fetching data types as numeric, avoid converting to UTF-8. I was unable to implement server-side cursors as Explained above. Thank you.

Comment: I understand that it's hard to know what to include, but remember that we have *no access at all to your code or environment*, we *only* have what you write in the question. A large part of debugging is ruling out things that are definitely *not* the cause, so one approach would be to try to eliminate Laravel from the mix: look at the SQL it's generating, and send that SQL directly to the DB using the PHP functions from the two different extensions. If you can reproduce the slow-down like that, you have made progress towards a [mre] you can share that will give others more chance to help you.

Comment: As you try to get there, you may discover instead that Laravel is _not_ sending the same query with the two drivers - perhaps it's using parameters differently, for instance. In that case, you can create a simplified example of _that_ difference, and ask about why that's happening.

Comment: @Yaakov as the other user mentioned, the idea is to rule out stuff, in this case I do think the culprit is the database, not Laravel, because if you only changed the driver and is slower, then Laravel should not be the issue at all, but the database or a configuration on the framework or the database. One way of testing this is for you to run the queries directy on the database and see if it still accounts for the same time. Another way is to also add `EXPLAIN` at the beginning of the query, so it shows you what it is going to do, but it requires that you understand what it is showing back